# How to make MP3 streaming in Android keep running when pressing back button on the screen or the phone?

Tags: android, button, save, back

I'll have 2 activities (screens) in my Android app, the 2-nd will appear after actions on the 1-st.
In the 2-nd I'll have a back button, that will take me to the 1-st screen.
How can I implement that if I have music playing on 2-nd screen so it won't stop after going back to the 1-st activity pressing a back button? (making it a service or some other choices?)

Also how to implement that music will play if I press Back button on the phone itself?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You answered this yourself-  make the music play on a Service.  That's the general answer whenever you want something to continue when your Activity doesn't have the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

The [Media Playback guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) specifically goes over the case where "you want to continue playing "background media" even when the user leaves your activity, much in the same way that the built-in Music application behaves. In this case, what you need is a MediaPlayer controlled by a Service".